# Show that a zero mean, stationary process with correlation < 0.5 only at lag 1 is representable as an MA(1)

Tags: time-series, stationarity, moving-average

I am trying to solve an exercise from *Time Series Analysis: with Applications in R* by Cryer and Chan.

> Suppose that ${Y_t}$ is a zero mean, stationary process with $|\rho_1|<0.5$ and $\rho_k=0$ for $k>1$. Show that ${Y_t}$ must be representable as an MA(1) process. That is, show that there is a white noise sequence ${e_t}$ such that $Y_t=e_t-\theta e_{t-1}$ where $\rho_1$ is correct and $e_t$ is uncorrelated with $Y_{t-k}$ for $k>0$. (Hint: Choose $\theta$ such that $|\theta| < 1$ and $\rho_1=-\theta/(1+\theta^2)$; then let $e_t = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \theta^j Y_{t-j}$.)

I have begun to try to derive $Y_t = e_t - \theta e_{t-1}$ by, as in the hint, setting
$$
\begin{align}
e_t & = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \theta^j Y_{t-j}\quad \text{and expanding into} \\
    & = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \theta^j Y_{t-j} + \theta^0 Y_{t-0} \\
    & \iff \\
Y_t & = e_t - \sum_{j=1}^\infty \theta^j Y_{t-j}
\end{align}
$$
but I don't know how to proceed from here.
I have also attempted to set $\theta$ to some value that satisfies the prerequisites, such as 0.4, but again: I'm not sure if that is helpful.

Comment: It seems that your title is wrong.  It looks like you are trying to say that an MA(1) stationary time series has an infinite autoregressive representation.

Comment: Hint:  You can write the expression as $(1 + \sum B^j\theta^j)Y_t = e_t$, where $B^j$ is the "backshift operator", defined such that $B^j Y_t = Y_{t-j}$.  Now you have a polynomial in $B\theta$ on the left hand side.  Does that resemble an infinite series expansion of a much simpler polynomial?